# Return a bad request when ID doesn't match

Tags: c#, rest, error-handling, stripe-payments

Trying to return a badrequest if the cardMethod.ID doesn't match the payment ID, but currently it returns a 500 internal server error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" Where or how would I go about returning an error based off the logic below. I wasn't sure if it should be handled in the controller or should be handed in the service layer.

As currently the service layer handles mostly stripe exceptions.

Or should I try implement a try catch in my controller?

service class

```
        public async Task<VersionResponse> DeletePaymentMethod(string paymentID, string userId)
        {
            try
            {
                StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = _appSettings.StripeSecretKey;

                var profile = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

                var stripeId = profile.StripeAccountId;

                if (stripeId == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException("No associated Stripe account found.");

                var service = new PaymentMethodService();

                //list the payment methods
                var cardPaymentMethods = service.ListAutoPaging(new PaymentMethodListOptions
                {
                    Customer = stripeId,
                    Type = "card"
                });

                //Detach card which matches with list of payment methods
                var cardMethod = cardPaymentMethods.Where(m => m.Id == paymentID).FirstOrDefault(); 

                if(cardMethod.Id != paymentID)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Payment method not found for specified id.");

                await service.DetachAsync(cardMethod.Id, new PaymentMethodDetachOptions());

                return new VersionResponse
                {
                    Data = cardPaymentMethods
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw HandleStripeExceptions(ex);
            }
        }
```

PaymentMethodController

```
        [HttpDelete]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult), 400)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeletePaymentMethod(string paymentID)
        {
            var userId = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "UserID").Value;
            var result = new SuccessResponse()
            {
                success = true
            };

            
            await _paymentService.DeletePaymentMethod(paymentID, userId);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(paymentID))
                return BadRequest("Payment method not found for specified id.");

            return Ok(result);
        }

    private Exception HandleStripeExceptions(Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex is StripeException e)
        {
            switch (e.StripeError.ErrorType)
            {
                case "card_error":
                    Console.WriteLine("Code: " + e.StripeError.Code);
                    Console.WriteLine("Message: " + e.StripeError.Message);
                    break;
                case "api_connection_error":
                    break;
                case "api_error":
                    break;
                case "missing_parameter":
                    break;
                case "authentication_error":
                    break;
                case "rate_limit_error":
                    break;
                case "validation_error":
                    break;

                default:
                    // Unknown Error Type
                    break;
            }

            return ex;
        }
        else
        {
            return ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug the code? which line in the code throws the exception?

Comment: Move `await _paymentService.DeletePaymentMethod(paymentID, userId);` below the `if()` check

Comment: @zaitsman I tried that but it still doesn't hit it - it throws a 500 error here                 if(cardMethod.Id != paymentID)
but doens't catch my exception

Comment: `_paymentService.DeletePaymentMethod` throws `HandleStripeExceptions` but it is not handled in the controller code...

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya so do I have to call HandleStripeExceptions? in my controller?

Comment: It would be more helpful to you to read about exception handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `500` error is a result of

```
if(cardMethod.Id != paymentID)
  throw new ArgumentException("Payment method not found for specified id.");
```

The cardMethod could be `null`, you should check `null` in the if statement like

```
if(cardMethod == null)
```

There will no case where `cardMethod.Id != paymentID` is true.

Comment: I've tried that for some reason it catches the error on that line - throws a System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

<cardMethod>5__6 was null.

Comment: but then when I step through it goes back to the controller and checks if deletepayments was successful if not it goes to my generic exception handler which will just return a 500 error message

Comment: Sorry, modified my answer a bit, you should check `if(cardMethod == null)`.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same output?